# Expiring in-memory cache module

Tags: python

I needed a simple expiring in-memory cache module for a project I'm working on and I've come up with the following.

My requirements for the cache module are:

1. Be able to expire objects after certain period of time
2. Use what we have in the standard library
3. Keep it simple

So far I've got this.

```
"""
Expiring in-memory cache module

"""

import logging
import threading

from time import time
from collections import OrderedDict

__all__ = ['CachedObject', 'CacheInventory', 'CacheException']


class CacheException(Exception):
      """
      Generic cache exception
      """
      pass


class CachedObject(object):
    def __init__(self, name, obj, ttl):
        """
        Initializes a new cached object

        Args:
            name               (str): Human readable name for the cached entry
            obj               (type): Object to be cached
            ttl                (int): The TTL in seconds for the cached object

        """
        self.hits = 0
        self.name = name
        self.obj = obj
        self.ttl = ttl
        self.timestamp = time()


class CacheInventory(object):
    """
    Inventory for cached objects

    """
    def __init__(self, maxsize=0, housekeeping=0):
        """
        Initializes a new cache inventory

        Args:
            maxsize      (int): Upperbound limit on the number of items
                                that will be stored in the cache inventory
            housekeeping (int): Time in minutes to perform periodic
                                cache housekeeping

        """
        if maxsize < 0:
            raise CacheException('Cache inventory size cannot be negative')

        if housekeeping < 0:
            raise CacheException('Cache housekeeping period cannot be negative')

        self._cache = OrderedDict()
        self.maxsize = maxsize
        self.housekeeping = housekeeping * 60.0
        self.lock = threading.RLock()

        if self.housekeeping > 0:
            threading.Timer(self.housekeeping, self.housekeeper).start()

    def __len__(self):
        with self.lock:
            return len(self._cache)

    def __contains__(self, key):
        with self.lock:
            if key not in self._cache:
                return False

            item = self._cache[key]
            if self._has_expired(item):
                return False
            return True

    def _has_expired(self, item):
        """
        Checks if a cached item has expired and removes it if needed

        If the upperbound limit has been reached then the last item
        is being removed from the inventory.

        Args:
            item (CachedObject): A cached object to lookup

        """
        with self.lock:
            if time() > item.timestamp + item.ttl:
                logging.debug(
                    'Object %s has expired and will be removed from cache [hits %d]',
                    item.name,
                    item.hits
                )
                self._cache.pop(item.name)
                return True
            return False

    def add(self, obj):
        """
        Add an item to the cache inventory

        Args:
            obj (CachedObject): A CachedObject instance to be added

        Raises:
            CacheException

        """
        if not isinstance(obj, CachedObject):
            raise Exception('Need a CachedObject instance to add in the cache')

        with self.lock:
            if self.maxsize > 0 and len(self._cache) == self.maxsize:
                popped = self._cache.popitem(last=False)
                logging.debug('Cache maxsize reached, removing %s [hits %d]', popped.name, popped.hits)

            logging.debug('Caching object %s [ttl: %d seconds]', obj.name, obj.ttl)
            self._cache[obj.name] = obj

    def get(self, key):
        """
        Retrieve an object from the cache inventory

        Args:
            key (str): Name of the cache item to retrieve

        Returns:
            The cached object if found, None otherwise

        """
        with self.lock:
            if key not in self._cache:
                return None

            item = self._cache[key]
            if self._has_expired(item):
                return None

            item.hits += 1
            logging.debug(
                'Returning object %s from cache [hits %d]',
                item.name,
                item.hits
            )

            return item.obj

    def housekeeper(self):
        """
        Remove expired entries from the cache on regular basis

        """
        with self.lock:
            expired = 0
            logging.info(
                'Starting cache housekeeper [%d items in cache]',
                len(self._cache)
            )
            for name, item in self._cache.items():
                if self._has_expired(item):
                    expired += 1
            logging.info(
                'Cache housekeeper completed [%d removed from cache]',
                expired
            )
            if self.housekeeping > 0:
                threading.Timer(self.housekeeping, self.housekeeper).start()
```

Here's an example usage of the caching module:

```
>>> from __future__ import print_function
>>> from __future__ import absolute_import
>>> from . import CachedObject
>>> from . import CacheInventory
>>> cache = CacheInventory(housekeeping=60) # housekeeper will run every 60 minutes
>>> obj = {'key1': 'value1', 'key2': 'value2'}
>>> cached_obj = CachedObject(name='mydictionary', obj=obj, ttl=60) # object will expire in 60 seconds
>>> cache.add(obj=cached_obj)
>>> print(cache.get('mydictionary'))
{'key2': 'value2', 'key1': 'value1'}
>>> # 60 seconds later -> the object has expired already
... 
>>> print(cache.get('mydictionary'))
None
```

I'm currently using this caching module for storing VMware vSphere managed objects and the code can also be found in Github:

- https://github.com/dnaeon/py-vconnector/blob/master/src/vconnector/cache.py

Any thoughts, remarks or suggestions about the design and implementation of this caching module?

**Note**: Code works in both Python 2 and Python 3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this loop you're not using `name`:

> ```
> for name, item in self._cache.items():
>     if self._has_expired(item):
>         expired += 1
> ```

If you only need the values, then iterate over just the values:

```
for item in self._cache.values():
    if self._has_expired(item):
        expired += 1
```

---

You don't need an `if` statement here:

> ```
> if self._has_expired(item):
>     return False
> return True
> ```

You can simplify by using the negated boolean expression directly:

```
return not self._has_expired(item)
```

---

This expression can be simplified:

> ```
> if self.maxsize > 0 and len(self._cache) == self.maxsize:
> ```

Using chained comparison:

```
if 0 < self.maxsize == len(self._cache):
```

Comment: Nice catches, will make sure to update the module to reflect these recommendations.